# Split between two delimiters

Tags: java, android, split

I have this information on a String:

```
0183600NEWDEVICE

0147900:4239

0147901:0200

0147902:2971

0157903:01598

0157904:02754

 0157905:03383

0157906:02590

0187908:04.02.01

0157909:19.45

 0117911:0

 0098540
```

I just want to have the last information (between ":" and "\n")

I mean: 4239, 0200, 2971, etc etc

I tried to use split:

```
 String[] result = readMessage.split(":|\n");
```

And it works, but I just want the information between ":" and "\n" not the rest. I mean:

```
result[0] = 4239
result[1] = 0200
result[2] = 2971
...
```

How can I solve it?

**EDIT:** After that I want to take "result" and put each part of it on a TextView

```
 For example:
    mTextView.setText("FEV = " + result[0] + "\n");
```

**MY SOLUTION: (THANKS TO EVERYBODY!)**

```
 String[] result = readMessage.split(":");
            int j=0;
            for (int i=0;i<result.length;i++){
                if (result[i].contains("\n")){
                    result[j] = result[i];
                    String [] result2 = result[j].split("\n");
                    result[j]=result2[0]; 
                    j++;
                }
            }
```

Comment: I don't think you can use a single regex to split that string like that, mainly because the portion you want is between 2 parts that you don't want. You can split by `\n` then for each element remove everything before `:` (included) using `replaceAll`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You might do something like this:

```
String str = "one:two";
String[] splitted = str.split(":");
```

Then you can do a check:

```
for (int i=0;i<splitted.length;i++){
    if (splitted[i].contains("\n")){
        splitted[i].replace("\n","");
    }
}
```

Comment: I used this solution to implement mine

Answer (score 2):

You could try the following instead of splitting -

```
Pattern p = Pattern.compile(".+:(.+)\n");
Matcher m = p.matcher(x);
List<String> fields = new ArrayList<String>();
while (m.find()) {
    fields.add(m.group(1));
}
```

Note: You might have to modify the regex.

Comment: `.+` should be non-greedy (`.+?`). Same with `.*`.

Answer (score 0):

Split will give you the array with W='wanted', N='not wanted'.

If your input pattern is stable, your output array will have pattern

NWNWNWNW...

So you could simply get the even index out.

---

The other solution is read by line (split by line works). Then looks for colon, and discard what you have before the colon (included).

Answer (score 0):

- you could build a new array, counting by twos:

  - for(int index=1; index<=result.size; index = index+2)
- or you could use a regex instead, specifying the second half

  - http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/regex/groups.html
  - http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/regex/Pattern.html

I'd do the regex route personally!

Answer (score 0):

Simply split on just the "\n" rather than on both the `\n` and the `:` for this to work.

```
string[] result = readMessage.split("\n");
```

And then:

```
String str = "test:one";
String lastBit = str.substring(str.indexOf(":")+1, str.length());
System.out.println(lastBit); //output = "one"
```

Alternatively, you could split each string once again on the `:` and take the second string ( for each string returned by the first split operation).

Answer (score 0):

```
List<String> output = new ArrayList<String>();
String[] lines = readMessage.split("\n");

for(String line : lines)
{    
     int index = line.indexOf(":");
     if(index != -1 && index < line.length)
     {
          output.add(line.substring(index + 1, line.length());
     }    
}
```